# Google Analytics Cohort analysis CSV, TSV and Google Sheets Download

Tags: google-sheets, google-analytics

When I perform a simple cohort analysis using the built in tools I am able to generate a table that looks like this:

[image]

However - When I try to download the table using the download button in the top right hand side:

[image]

and try to download in TSV, CSV or Google sheets - I get a useless output that looks like this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Is it a bug with Google Analytics?
I can't seem to find a solution online?

I wish to get the table produced in CSV or Google Sheets format.

Comment: The thing is that this is a very basic feature.  If you want something more advanced you really should look into using the api or one of the addons for excel or google sheets.

Comment: @DaImTo I dont understand why the download button doesnt work though? If I click on PDF it gives me the exact view of what I am looking for -> but CSV doesnt?
What adons would you recomend ?-> The analytics api seems to not be supported for web+app properties and I have been waiting 4 months to get on the tester list.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se] Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask]. Start by looking at [webmasters.se] and the official Google Analytics Help Center.

Comment: @Rubén -Thanks for the advice. I have shown all the steps to reproduce the problem and everything I have tried to solve it. Im not sure what further you would like me to add.

Comment: Before posting a question you should try to find if someone else already posted something about a similar problem. If you already did that, please share with us the most relevent findings, if you didn't, please do it.